# Amazon EC2 AWS hosting. Installed Wordpress, but can't find wp-content folder with SFTP

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sudo

Tried to find the solution online but I'm so frustrated.
I barely can code, I understand the structure and such though. 
So I'm using the 12 Months free amazon hosting, started using it because the amazon CDN kind of didn't work on my hosting and I'm tired of my hosting anyway.
Hosting24, always slow, the problem with the DNS and first byte.

SO. I connected to my amazon ec2 via filezilla. With all the sftp, ppk keys and such.
And I see the var folder, but no www folder in the var folder. 
That is where I suppose is the wp-content folder.

I Have a basic Wordpress Theme running right now and upon right clicking and view SOURCE I see that it is located on 55.313.xxx.xxx/wp-content/themes/.....
But I can't find the wp-content folder or anything related to it and themes.

I'm using ubuntu/ bitnami wordpress on it. So my username is ubuntu.
Tried to give myself /var/www rights but such folder doesn't exist.
Not sure what to do.
I'd appreciate for a swift reply.
Thank you.

EDIT: HOLLY BUDDHA!!!!!! You know... I've had this problem for a few days now and I couldn't find a solution, but I SOMEHOW found it under **/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content**
I would have never thought to look under **APPS**...
I'm so sorry. so I didn't even need to give myself permissions or whatsoever... people confused me so much here...

Hope I helped someone else other than myself xD

Comment: Make a comment and mark it as answered if you can. /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content for those that may miss it, op edited above.